# rewrite all requests from one folder to a parent folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This one has me stumped, I need to re-write all requests to the javascript folder (js) to a special library handler system.

e.g.

```
rewrite http://localhost/admin/js/bar.js  --> http://localhost/_lib/=admin/js/bar.js
```

Any ideas?  I have tried the following which creates an error

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/_lib/$1 [NC]

(36)File name to long: cannot map GET /admin/js/bar.js to file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?admin/js/(.*).js$ /_lib/=admin/js/$1.js [L]
```